# how much to rotate a plane to keep the length the same

Tags: trigonometry

I have this "scene" where there is a plane with points $1,2$ and an arbitrary length $l$  that intersects two lines.

[image: original]

What I want to know is: how much do I need to rotate the plane in order for it to be "inverted", i.e. point $1$ cuts the lower line, and point $2$ cuts the upper line.

Additionally, after rotating the plane, the distance between $1$ and $2$ should remain the same at $l$
[image: inverted]

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  What is your math background/education?

Comment: the source is that I am developing a 3D program that is currently looking at a cylinder and the top of that cylinder gets projected as an ellipse with a short radius of $l$. the issue is that I am looking at the cylinder from the wrong angle (through the cylinder instead of from the top). so I want to rotate the camera so that the short radius is the same, but the camera looks at it from the correct angle. My math background is pretty limited to what was taught in computer science bachelors 8 years ago

Comment: First of all, I personally don't know the answer, or else I would respond with a solution.  Second of all, your original posting **was** missing details, as per [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  Third, by responding as you have done, in my opinion, you have transformed your posting from low quality to high quality.  My only (minor) criticism is that the information in your responding comment belongs directly in the posted question, as per the protocol article.